# Travis CI After Success Write to a File in GitHub Repo

Tags: shell, github, continuous-integration, travis-ci, webhooks

I have the following script that I kind of started to write in one of my projects where I use Travis CI.

```
after_success:
  - MESSAGE=$(git log --format=%B -n 1 $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER)
  - git clone git://${GH_REPO}
  - git config user.email "travis@travis.org"
  - git config user.name "travis"
  - git add .
  - git commit --allow-empty -m "updated README.md"
  - git push https://joesan:${GITHUB_API_KEY}@${GH_REPO} HEAD:master
```

So with the above script, I want to do the following:

1. cd into the directory  (after git clone) that contains the file called deployment-version.txt
2. Replace the contents of the deployment-version.txt with the new version number which I get from TRAVIS_BUILD_VERSION variable

So my deployment-version.txt has the following ocntent:

```
plant-simulator-version=512
```

So with this after success script, assuming that the TRAVIS_BUILD_VERSION is 513, then I expect

```
plant-simulator-version=513
```

as my new content and I want this file to be pushed into the repo! Any clues how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this by writing a new file which simply contains just one line of text. This is for now Okay! Hence I'm posting this as a solution:

```
after_success:
  - MESSAGE=$(git log --format=%B -n 1 $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER)
  - git clone https://${GH_REPO}
  - cd ${PLANT_SIMULATOR_DEPLOYMENT_REPO_NAME}
  - rm deployment-version.txt    # Remove the file
  - touch deployment-version.txt # Add the file
  - echo plant-simulator.version=${TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER} >> deployment-version.txt
  - git config user.email "travis@travis.org"
  - git config user.name ${USER} # this email and name can be set anything you like
  - git add .
  - git commit --allow-empty -m "release version for deployment  tagged with version $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"
  - git push https://${GITHUB_API_KEY}@${GH_REPO} HEAD:master
```